# Multiple contexts in liquibase properties file

Tags: liquibase

How can I define multiple contexts to be used in liquibase property file.

This is the content of my property file.

```
changeLogFile: db.changelog-master.yaml
changelogSchemaName: example
contexts: db-creation and initial-data
defaultSchemaName: schemadb
driver: org.h2.Driver
```

Neither db-creation nor initial-data context are performed.

Comment: 1. This is what I did
2. This is what I expected to happen
3. This is what actually happened.

Comment: The three items are described in the question. Of course that unordered but are there.

Comment: I disagree. I don't know what command you issued. Are you using command line, maven, something else? When you say "Neither db-creation nor initial-data context are performed" what does that mean (i.e. what changes did you expect did happen that didn't happen, or what changes happened that you didn't expect to happen. 

Here is what I think your question should look like:
When using version 3.1.2 of the liquibase command line tools, when I run 'liquibase update' with the following properties file and properties file (attached) then I expect that when I look in the database using ... I see ...

Comment: I am not trying to be difficult, but I cannot help you without more information.

Comment: I see. So, I'm using maven. db-creation and initial-data are contexts defined in scripts (using yaml format). When I perfomr mvn liquibase;update, neither the scripts associated with db-creation (one context) nor scripts associated with initial-data (other context) are performed.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I notice is that you use "and" in this line:

`contexts: db-creation and initial-data`

The only changesets that would be deployed in that case are those that have **both** those contexts. If you use "OR", then you might get the behavior you expect.

Comment: Hi @SteveDonie, thanks for you answer. But "OR" also didn't work. I have noticed in documentation that:     
**Using a “,” to separate contexts works like an OR operation but with the highest precedence.**    
Using comma works for me.  
  
Thanks

Comment: Excellent - glad to hear.